# Hybrid_Auth "Google returned an invalid response."

Tags: hybridauth

HI I am using Hybrid_Auth , its working good but it has following problem in flow

- > $hybridauth = new Hybrid_Auth($config); $social =
  >   $hybridauth->authenticate("Google"); //works  When I call
  >   $user_profile = $social->getUserProfile();//exception

It gives me this problem, Google returned an invalid response.

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue by going to google console and enable google+ api

https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth